# Symfony 4.4 https everywhere

Tags: https, symfony4

I want my Symfony 4.4 site to force https site wide. I know this should be simple and I've been googling for a while but I don't seem to be able to find the correct solution. I have paths defined in my security.yaml file for pages behind a login. I tried adding "requires_channel: https" to those and then added one to catch everything else and it killed my site:

```
- { path: ^/marketing/page1, roles: ROLE_USER, requires_channel: https }
- { path: ^/marketing/page2, roles: ROLE_USER, requires_channel: https }
- { path: ^/marketing/page3, roles: ROLE_USER, requires_channel: https }
# catch all other URLs
- {path: '^/', roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANNONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https}
```

With those rules in place I was unable to connect at all in a browser. I do not have a cert for this, but I still expected to get the "this site is not secure do you want to proceed page". Am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Thanks